# How to implementation Polymer 1.0 layout

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

My `index.html` is like this

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Keyboard</title>
        <!-- 1. Load webcomponent support before any code that touches the DOM -->
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="elements/each-key.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
        <style>
            #keyboard-layout {
              @apply(--layout-horizontal);
            }
        </style>
      </head>
        <body>
            <div id="keyboard-layout">
                <each-key english="A" shiftup="ꯃ" shiftdown="ꯝ"></each-key>
                <each-key english="A" shiftup="ꯃ" shiftdown="ꯝ"></each-key>
                <each-key english="A" shiftup="ꯃ" shiftdown="ꯝ"></each-key>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm expecting `each-key` will be arranged side by side (like `float:left`); however it is not (and `each-key` still behaves like `display:block`). I've my `each-key.html` as

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">


<dom-module id="each-key">
    <style>
        .key{
            min-height: 50px;
            max-height: 80px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.6);
            position: relative;
        }

            paper-ripple {
              color: #4285f4;
            }

        .key>div { position: absolute; }
        .top-left { left: 4px; top: 4px; }
        .top-right { right: 4px; top: 0; }
        .bottom-left { left: 4px; bottom: 4px; }
        .bottom-right { right: 4px; bottom: 0; }

    </style>
    <template>
        <div class="key" >
            <div class="top-left"></div>
            <div class="top-right">{{shiftdown}}</div>
            <div class="bottom-left">{{english}}</div>
            <div class="bottom-right">{{shiftup}}</div>

            <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'each-key',
    properties: {
        'english' : String,
        'shiftup': String,
        'shiftdown': String
    }
  });
</script>
```

1. Is there something I'm missing here?
2. In the documentation, https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#layout-attributes, in the `<style>` section, what what does it mean by `/*layout properties for the host element */` (what is a host element?) and `/* layout properties for a local DOM element */` (what is a local DOM in this context? local DOM === shadow DOM?) ?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I found this "illustrated" guide to the various layout classes really useful: http://plnkr.co/edit/xIARqr?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

The CSS mixins only work inside `dom-module`'s, the classes work outside as well - I don't know why, I had to try it out as well...

This would work:

```
<body class="layout horizontal">
```

But the more polymeric way would probably be to wrap the complete thing inside a dom-module:

```
<dom-module id="all-keys">
<style>
  #keyboard-layout {
    @apply(--layout);
    @apply(--layout-horizontal);
  }
</style>
<template>
  <div id="keyboard-layout" >
    <each-key english="A" shiftup="U" shiftdown="D"></each-key>
    <each-key english="A" shiftup="U" shiftdown="D"></each-key>
    <each-key english="A" shiftup="U" shiftdown="D"></each-key>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({is: 'all-keys'});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

If you also add a `min-width` to your `each-key` then this works ok:

```
<dom-module id="each-key">
<style>
  :host {
    min-width: 50px;
  }
```

or alternatively:

```
<dom-module id="each-key">
<style>
  :host {
    @apply(--layout-flex);
  }
```

This also answers your question two: `:host` is to determine the attributes of the dom-module instance.

In other words, you can leave the `<div id="keyboard-layout" >` away:

```
<dom-module id="all-keys">
  <style>
  :host {
    @apply(--layout);
    @apply(--layout-horizontal);
    }
  </style>
  <template>
      <each-key english="A" shiftup="U" shiftdown="D"></each-key>
      <each-key english="A" shiftup="U" shiftdown="D"></each-key>
      <each-key english="A" shiftup="U" shiftdown="D"></each-key>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({is: 'all-keys'});
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The complete working source is on: http://jsbin.com/qanesapupo/1/edit?html,output